# Make react-router-dom v6 pass path as key to rendered element

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I think I may need a paradigm shift in my thinking here, so I'm open to those kinds of answers as well here.

Consider the following simplified example:

```js
export const App = (p: { apiClient: SomeApiClient }) => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/posts/:postId" element={<Post apiClient={p.apiClient} />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}

export const Home = () => {
  return <h1>Home!</h1>
}

export const Post = (p: { apiClient: SomeApiClient }) => {
  const { postId } = useParams();
  const [ state, setState ] = useState<PostState>({ status: "loading" });

  // When the component mounts, get the specified post from the API
  useEffect(() => {
    if (state.status === "loading") {
      (async () => {
        const post = await p.apiClient.getPost(postId);
        setState({ status: "ready", post });
      })();
    }
  })

  return (
    <h2>Posts</h2>
    {
      state.status === "loading"
      ? <p>Loading....</p>
      : <div className="post">
        <h3>{state.post.title}</h3>
        <div className="content">{state.post.content}</div>
      </div>
    }
  )
}

export type PostState =
  | { status: "loading" }
  | { status: "ready"; post: BlogPost };
export type BlogPost = { title: string; content: string };
```

This works fine the first time, but pretend there's a `<Link />` on the page that goes to the next post. When I click that link, the URL changes, but the page content doesn't, because React Router is not actually re-mounting the `<Post .../>` component. That component correctly receives the updated postId and is *re-rendered*, but since it doesn't get *re-mounted*, the `useEffect` logic doesn't run again and the content stays the same.

I've been solving this very awkwardly by creating intermediary components like so:

```js
export const App = (p: { apiClient: SomeApiClient }) => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/posts/:postId" element={<PostRenderer apiClient={p.apiClient} />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}

export const PostRenderer = (p: { apiClient: SomeApiClient }) => {
  const { postId } = useParams();
  return <Post key={postId} postId={postId} apiClient={p.apiClient} />
}

export const Post = (p: { postId: string; apiClient: SomeApiClient }) => {
  // ....
}
```

But I'm starting to get a lot of those, and literally all they do is take the param from the URL and use it as a key on the actual target component. I've read through the react-router-dom docs and am not finding anything that indicates there's a way to automate this. I must be thinking about this wrong.... Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Sorry this is late - I ended up doing something very similar to your `PostRenderer` component as that way there's a different key for every post in the route. PostRenderer is reusable too, so I didn't really see that as an issue. The accepted answer wouldn't work for setting the initial state of `useState` since as per this post https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state#option-2-resetting-state-with-a-key we aren't ever resetting the state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a more common and practical solution is to add the `postId` as a dependency to the `useEffect` to rerun the asynchronous logic when the route param changes.

Example:

```
export const Post = (p: { apiClient: SomeApiClient }) => {
  const { postId } = useParams();
  const [state, setState] = useState<PostState>({ status: "loading" });

  // When the post id updates, get the specified post from the API
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPostById = async (postId) => {
      setState({ status: "loading" });
      const post = await p.apiClient.getPost(postId);
      setState({ status: "ready", post });
    };

    fetchPostById(postId);
  }, [postId]);

  return (
    <h2>Posts</h2>
    {
      state.status === "loading"
      ? <p>Loading....</p>
      : <div className="post">
        <h3>{state.post.title}</h3>
        <div className="content">{state.post.content}</div>
      </div>
    }
  )
};
```

Comment: Aha! Thanks for the push. I'll refactor around this pattern and see if it helps clean things up. I'm pretty new to react, so I wouldn't be surprised if this simple shift ameliorates my problems. I'll come back and accept this answer if it ends up getting me home.

Comment: @kael If it even gets you closer to home it's an improvement, right? Let me know if it helps, and if we need to refine it we can.

Comment: Ok! After a major refactor, this proved a very useful suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: @kael Great to hear, and glad to help. Cheers and good luck!